# Convert a number string to int8 or uint8

Tags: php, string, hex

I need help converting numbers (string) to int8 or uint8 using PHP.

Example: number `10` should be `0A`

How can I do this?

Comment: Try [`dechex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it seems like you want to do has nothing to do with signed or unsigned integers, you're just converting an integer to its hexadecimal representation. In PHP, that can be done with `dechex`.

`dechex(10)` will return 0xA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to convert a number to its hexdecimal string representation

```
echo dechex(intval("10"));
```

There is also a [Hexdump](http://www.metashock.de/pirum/) function available for php. This may help too.

You'll find more info [here](http://www.metashock.de/?p=412)

Comment: Not quite.  `ord` returns the ASCII code, not a number's hex value.

Comment: srry, this was the result of thinking too fast. ;)